# Angular: Use custom HTTP-header entries

Tags: angular, http

I try to set a custom HTTP-header with Angular HttpClient.

```
this.http.get ("http://localhost/test", {responseType: "json"});
```

produces a HTTP-GET (what I expected).

If I try setting a custom header-entry X-TOKEN then

```
this.http.get ("http://localhost/test", {headers: new HttpHeaders().set('X-TOKEN',"123"), responseType: "json"});
```

it is not anymore a GET but an OPTION with Access-Control-Request.

```
OPTIONS /test HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Access-Control-Request-Headers: x-token
```

But I expected a HTTP-GET with an additional line in the header

```
X-TOKEN: 123
```

So whats wrong?

Comment: Learn about CORS pre-flight requests.

Answer (score 0):

With the new X-TOKEN option it's failing so it's not allowing the get to run. You need to add the X-TOKEN to your ACCESS-CONTROL-ALLOW-HEADERS (see [more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Headers)) on your server side.

Comment: If you don't set headers, you don't get an OPTIONS requests.

Comment: Thanks I was thinking of an older request library that did pre-flight check on all requests.